getting url from DID for post http request
I have a server written in Golang. There is a mobile application that generates a token and sends it to the endpoint of my server. The server parses the token and gets access to the "from" field, where the token was sent from is indicated in DID format. I need to generate a request for the mobile application and send it back using DID. How can I get a URL from DID?
I have DID
did:iden3:polygonid:polygon:amoy:2Sh9N2ciV9VAv3RNEUv8WMTtiB6iREepUNreftLfvC
This is the DID of the application from which the request came. I need to send him a request back by mail. How can I get a legal name where to send a request? or can I submit a request for a DID?
